# I am unable to add a line using the <hr> tag in HTML

Tags: html, css

```css
 .yellow-line{
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 10px bold red;
}
```

```html
 <img class="vox-logo" src="images/vox_logo.JPG" alt="Vox Logo">
      <div class="header">
        <h5 class="menu-0">EXPLAINERS</h5>
        <h5 class="menu-1">POLITICS AND POLICY</h5>
        <h5 class="menu-2">WORLD</h5>
        <h5 class="menu-3">CULTURE</h5>
        <h5 class="menu-4">SCIENCE AND HEALTH</h5>
        <h5 class="menu-5">IDENTITIES</h5>
        <h5 class="menu-6">MORE</h5>
        <img class="twitter" src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
        <img class="facebook" src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook">
        <img class="youtube" src="images/youtube.png" alt="YouTube">
        <img class="rss" src="images/rss.png" alt="RSS">
        <img class="people" src="images/people.png" alt="People">
        <img class="search" src="images/search.png" alt="Search">
      </div>
      <br>
      <hr/>
      <div>
        <hr class="yellow-line">
      </div>
```

I cannot add a line after the div. Please check the given code above.

Please help me with this as I am trying to find a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Remove the `position:absolute` it's completely superfluous

Comment: Are you really using Visual Web Developer? That product was phased out years ago. Considering this question does not seem to have anything to do with the IDE you are using, please [edit] your question and remove that tag.

Answer (score 2):

First, your syntax is wrong. It should be `border-top: 10px solid red;`
And no need to give position absolute and overflow auto to hr tag.

Try this: `border-top: 10px solid red;`

Answer (score 0):

Hi your syntax for `border` is wrong there is nothing called `bold` use `solid` or any other option. `position` is not required but if you still want it.

please specify the width to the element like this. or give its parent `position: relative` so that it can place within the parent.

```css
 .yellow-line{
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 10px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <img class="vox-logo" src="images/vox_logo.JPG" alt="Vox Logo">
      <div class="header">
        <h5 class="menu-0">EXPLAINERS</h5>
        <h5 class="menu-1">POLITICS AND POLICY</h5>
        <h5 class="menu-2">WORLD</h5>
        <h5 class="menu-3">CULTURE</h5>
        <h5 class="menu-4">SCIENCE AND HEALTH</h5>
        <h5 class="menu-5">IDENTITIES</h5>
        <h5 class="menu-6">MORE</h5>
        <img class="twitter" src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
        <img class="facebook" src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook">
        <img class="youtube" src="images/youtube.png" alt="YouTube">
        <img class="rss" src="images/rss.png" alt="RSS">
        <img class="people" src="images/people.png" alt="People">
        <img class="search" src="images/search.png" alt="Search">
      </div>
      <br>
      <hr/>
      <div style="position:relative;">
        <hr class="yellow-line">
      </div>
```